# How to connect page control to scroller in xcode?

Tags: xcode, user-interface, scroller, pagecontrol

I'm following this tutorial [here](http://www.chupamobile.com/tutorial/details/81/Custom+PageControl/)   and have just finished. I was wondering if anybody could help me figure out how to animate this so that the images move in and out on swipe. I've looked around and can't find an answer. Also I would like to do it programmatically to.

Thanks.